# Send report of all changed or updated content in past day?

Tags: 7, notifications, rules

Trying to use Rules to do this but I think it's a bit too complicated.

I want to specify a time interval - say 24 hours - and generate an email report that lists all of the content that has been changed or created.

I can do this for individual items quite easily, but I'm looking for an aggregate report that someone could look at in the morning or evening to get a general overview of all the content changes.

I did stumble across the [Views Rules](https://drupal.org/project/views_rules) module, which is interesting. It would allow me to create a view containing all the new content or updated content in the past xx hours and present that data to Rules. But it seems that would still just allow me to loop over the data and send out individual emails.

I could of course just write a small module to do this as well, but I'm wondering if there's an existing solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you loooked at message notify?
Have a look at the [blog post](http://www.gizra.com/content/message-notify-multilingual-email-notifications/) by gizra 
or watch the [video](http://vimeo.com/63919900), message notify allows you to use view as the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian There is the [Report](https://www.drupal.org/project/report) module for D6 that does this. If you are doing something custom, might as well port it to D7.

Some details from the module's project page:

> The Report module provides an overview of user and content activity on your site.
>
> Historical data is collected through a daily cron job, and can be viewed in Daily/Weekly/Monthly/Annual tabular summaries. The Chart module will be also used for presentation, if available.
>
> Collected user data includes daily counts for registration, logins, and access for selected roles. Content data includes daily counts of nodes and comments created for selected node types.

I have not have not used this module so I cannot say how close it comes to what you exactly need.